# Deploying Rails with ActionCable to Nginx/Puma running over HTTPS in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano3, puma, actioncable

I am trying to deploy a Rails 5.0.1 application to a production server running Ubuntu, Nginx and Puma with Capistrano. The app used to work great until we added ActionCable. Everything (including ActionCable) works perfectly in the development environment but ActionCable just won't connect when the application is deployed to production.

I have followed [this tutorial](http://spannersoftware.com/rails-5-puma-nginx-actioncable/) to get the basic setup...

### The problem:

The issue is that every time a browser attempts a WebSocket handshake, the request is 301 redirected...

#### Browser JavaScript Console feedback:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://app.example.com/cable' failed: Unexpected response code: 301
```

#### Nginx access log feedback:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [07/Jun/2017:17:16:22 +0800] "GET /cable HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4"
```

#### `$ curl -v https://app.example.com/cable`:

```
*   Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to app.example.com (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate: app.example.com
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
> GET /cable HTTP/1.1
> Host: app.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Wed, 07 Jun 2017 11:42:27 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://puma/cable
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host app.example.com left intact
```

### The setup:

#### `nginx.conf`:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/appname/shared/tmp/sockets/appname-puma.sock;
}

server { # Primary server block
  # Bind port(s)
  listen  80;
  # listen  [::]:80;
  listen  443 ssl;

  # Bind domain(s)
  server_name app.example.com;

  # Bind certificate(s)
  ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/app.example.com/ssl-bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/app.example.com/app.example.com.key;

  root /home/deploy/apps/appname/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/appname/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/appname/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  # ActionCable
  location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://puma;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # Let Rails see current protocol
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  #error_page 503 /503.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

#### `cable.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

If any more information would be helpful, let me know!

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When it tries to establish a websocket connection, is there anything in the Rails application log? What happens if you run `curl -v https://app.example.com/cable`?

Comment: @will_in_wi Thanks for your response. No, there is nothing relating to the ActionCable connection attempts in the rails log... I have added the response from the curl command in the question above, good idea! 301 redirecting to `https://puma/cable` doesn't seem right... Or does Nginx know how to handle that?...

Comment: This hits my limits of Nginx knowledge. I'd look up the docs for proxypass. It seems like it is redirecting instead of proxying for some reason

Comment: @slehmann36 - did you ever get this to run? If you're the one who sent me an email with a piece of NGiNX conf - thx - but it did not fix it :( Yeap I'm the guy spamming the entire *net* right now in his efforts to find the answer to this question - see https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1189

Comment: @walt_die Yes, changing the `/cable` location block to be more in-line with the one I supplied you in the GitHub issue yesterday was the fix for me. You have restarted Nginx on the server to apply the config changes?

Comment: @slehmann36 thx - and good for you :) It changes not a single bit for me, I'm afraid - and I restart Puma and restart NGiNX at every single change

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, eventually copied in a few more directives from [here](https://deanpcmad.com/2017/rails-5-actioncable-nginx-and-puma-in-production/):

```
location /cable {
  proxy_pass http://puma;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Restarted nginx and puma and it started working.

I also explicitly set `config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'` and `config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'https://example.com' ]` in `config/environments/production.rb`, which you don't mention, but that was way before I got nginx working so not sure if actually necessary.

Comment: I don't have to configure `config.action_cable.url` but the headers you shared here helped to fix the issues. Thanks for sharing.