# Rails ActionCable on Puma and Nginx not working on production after deploy via capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma, actioncable

I create a website using `ActionCable` via Rails on top of **Puma** and **Nginx** on production.

But after deploying to the Production server seems like ActionCable is not working because of this `problem.WebSocket` connection to

```
WebSocket connection to 
'ws://sub.domain.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

This is my `production.rb`

```
config.action_cable.url = 'ws://sub.domain.com/cable'
config.web_socket_server_url = "ws://sub.domain.com/cable"
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, /https:\/\/*/]
config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```

This is my nginx.conf

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/app_name/shared/tmp/sockets/app_name-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/deploy/apps/app_name/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/app_name/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/app_name/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }
  
  location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://puma;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

    # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    # proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    # proxy_redirect off;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

My **puma.rb**

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }
plugin :tmp_restart
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "production" }
daemonize true
pidfile '/home/deploy/apps/app_name/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid'
```

How can I fix this and make `ActionCable` work on production?

Comment: What do you see in Nginx logs?

Comment: @TarunLalwani i got this `client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 124.120.187.175, server: 0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: Do you run action cable in `cable/config.ru` ?

Comment: Rails and Puma version ?

Comment: @MaicolBen yes already. But It is so confused, when i change my internet to using 4G from my phone it is working well. But with ADSL home internet it keeps rejecting like in the question, Any idea on this?

Comment: Have you perhaps tried to move the `location /cable` block above the `location @puma` block and changing it to something more specific like `location = /cable`?

EDIT (clarification):
It seems to me that your request is being passed to the `@puma` location instead of the `/cable` location.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should uncomment

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_redirect off;
```

headers in location /cable block, it usually not working because of them, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45826295/821305) answer